# Excel error bars from 1 value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to replicate a plot that was done in Excel (not originally by me), but the error bars don't make sense. Based on the table below, Excel produces the attached plot (1 value:1 point on the line). I can include standard error bars in the plot easily, but I don't understand how a standard error can be calculated from a single value - so, what is Excel actually calculating? Why can I add standard error bars to a single value in the plot, but I couldn't calculate them by hand individually?

```
Month   A       B       C   Total
5   0.179   0.326   0.017   0.522
6   0.604   0.14    0.444   1.188
7   0.303   1.152   0.545   2
8   1.042   0.444   1.108   2.594
9   1.2945  0.126   0.18    1.6005
10  0.975   0.168   0.361   1.504
11  0.837   0.153   0       0.99

# Standard error:
=STDEV(G7)/SQRT(COUNT(G7))
#DIV/0!
```

[image]

Microsoft documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/add-change-or-remove-error-bars-in-a-chart-e6d12c87-8533-4cd6-a3f5-864049a145f0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel you can generally specify different error bars (e.g., standard error, percentage etc.). In your case it seems that you use the "standard error" option.

The vertical bars in this context show the interval around the value of one standard error, i.e.,

```
(x – s.e., x + s.e.)
```

Assuming for the moment that you only have the `Months` column and the `Total` column stored in the range `A1:B8`. Now you can compute the standard error, which is equal to the standard deviation divided by the square root of the total number of samples. This implies the following computation:

```
standard error = stdev/sqrt(count)

=STDEV(B2:B8)/SQRT(COUNT(B2:B8))
```

Now you add/subtract from each value in column `Total` the standard error (computed in cell `E2`) to receive the lower (e.g., `=B2-$E$2`) and upper bound (e.g., `=B2+$E$2`), respectively.

That this is the correct way can be shown with the  following chart, for which the lower and upper bounds coincide with the standard errors provided by Excel:

[image: Output]

The data and computation looks as follows:

| Month | Total | Total_low | Total_high | standard error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0.52 | 0.27 | 0.78 | 0.26 |
| 6 | 1.19 | 0.93 | 1.44 |  |
| 7 | 2.00 | 1.74 | 2.26 |  |
| 8 | 2.59 | 2.34 | 2.85 |  |
| 9 | 1.60 | 1.34 | 1.86 |  |
| 10 | 1.50 | 1.25 | 1.76 |  |
| 11 | 0.99 | 0.73 | 1.25 |  |